# Async / Await Try Catch Error Handling

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using the JSONPlaceholder API: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com. I have the following in my `service.ts`:

```
public async getPosts(): Promise<Post[]> {
    try {
        const response = await this._http.get<Post[]>(this._baseUrl + "api/JsonPlaceholder/GetPosts");
        return response.toPromise();
    } catch (error) {
        await this.handleError(error);
    }
}
```

Which I try to use in my `component.ts`:

```
public posts: Post[];

public async ngOnInit() {
    const posts = await this._placeholderService.getPosts();
    this.posts = posts;
}
```

However, the TypeScript compiler throws an error on `public async getPosts(): Promise<Post[]>` - `Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.`

It is expecting a return statement in either the catch block or outside the try-catch. What is best practice for handling errors like this when I want to return a specific type...in my case `Post[]`. Is there a better way to structure these types of calls?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What does `handleError` do? What do you want to happen when the http request fails? Right now you are swallowing the error and returning `undefined`. You could fix your return type annotation as `Promise<Post[] | undefined>` (or remove it which will infer that type), then you need to handle the `undefined` case in upstream code:

```
public async ngOnInit() {
    const posts = await this._placeholderService.getPosts();
    if (posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    } else {
        this.errorMessage = "Failed to load posts!";
    }
}
```

Or you could just `return []` if you aren't handling the error case anyway:

```
} catch (error) {
    await this.handleError(error);
    return [];
}
```

Or you could throw the error and allow upstream code to handle it or not:

```
} catch (error) {
    await this.handleError(error);
    throw error;
}

public async ngOnInit() {
    try {
        const posts = await this._placeholderService.getPosts();
        this.posts = posts;
    } catch(error) {
        // Note that 'error' could be almost anything: http error, parsing error, type error in getPosts(), handling error in above code
        this.errorMessage = "Failed to load posts!";
    }
}
```

Comment: When an HTTP request fails, I want to notify the user somehow and fail gracefully. Currently, if `const response = await this._http.get<Post[]>(this._baseUrl + "api/JsonPlaceholder/GetPosts");` fails (say the URL endpoint is wrong) I'm getting an `Uncaught (in promise)` exception. The `const response` is of type `Observable<Post[]>` which doesn't have a status. How would I structure this to get a status?

Comment: @RyanBuening It sounds like you should let the thrown error through or re-throw it and handle it where you try to call `getPosts()` by displaying a message to the user. I updated my last example to show this.

Comment: That seems to work. I have the following: https://gist.github.com/ryanbuening/102d96807e5557e072d82f2b6f359384. If I load the page where I run this code with an incorrect endpoint I get the alert `Error!` with a 500 error logged in my console. However, if I refresh again, I get `NodeInvocationException: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: alert is not defined`. Do you know why I would be getting that and not the alert error message again? Does it have to do with me using server side rendering? (I'm using ASP.NET Core with JavaScriptServices https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices)

Answer (score 6):

> It is expecting a return statement in either the catch block or outside the try-catch. What is best practice for handling errors like this when I want to return a specific type...in my case Post[]. Is there a better way to structure these types of calls?

Simple annotation to reflect the true nature of the code you have written:

```
public async getPosts(): Promise<Post[] | undefined> { // notice `undefined`
    try {
        const response = await this._http.get<Post[]>(this._baseUrl + "api/JsonPlaceholder/GetPosts");
        return response.toPromise();
    } catch (error) {
        await this.handleError(error);
    }
}
```

TypeScript is just pointing out this truth for you